# Почему "дом терпимости"?

Tags: фразеология

Здравствуйте!
Публичные дома, особенно раньше, называли еще домами терпимости? А почему? К чему там терпимость?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Дом терпимости - это дом, который не одобряется и лишь по снисхождению терпится.

Это цитата из Толково-фразеологического словаря Михельсона. Интересно, что если б эту кальку с французского переводили бы сейчас, то скорее всего перевели бы как "дом толерантности"

Answer (score 3):

Это перевод с французского - maison de tolerance (дом толерантности), переведено на русский как "дом терпимости". В начале 19 века, в период регламентаризма, проституцию не запрещали.

"А знаете, почему публичные дома иногда называют «домами терпимости»?Началось с Великой французской революции (конец XVIII века) -тогда на волне демократических порывов решили, что проститутка тоже человек, а значит, и относиться к ней тоже надо как к человеку. Публичные дома тогда переименовали в «дома толерантности», мол, мы терпимо относимся к явлению, пусть женщины работают себе, не будем их осуждать. В Россию выражение из города Парижа принесли русские войска после войны 1812 года". http://www.baby.ru/blogs/post/127862429-123761729/

В наше время значение слова переосмыслено: общественность как бы терпит такой неправильный дом.

Answer (score 1):

Толерантности тут не хватит для объяснения. Дом, заведение (любое другое явление и структура, нарушающая закон) терпится не только законопослушными социальными группами, но и теневыми формированиями. Дом терпимости в данном случае показывает неофициальное отношение властей на произвол: смотрят сквозь пальцы.

Answer (score -2):

"дом терпимости" - это не что-то обобщённое или конкретизированное. В общем, гносеологическом смысле, дом терпимости - это место, тип общества, способы коммуникации и пр. при которых кто-то "терпит" кого-то. Т.е. проявляет толерантность. Более того, как само понятие "дом" может рассматриваться в контексте "человеческое тело", так и та самая "терпимость" может направлена на самоё себя. Тогда это явление, по сути дела, "претерпевает" тот самый "дом"

Comment: Не ожидайте проявления толерантности к отсутствию прописной и точки как признака фразы. На будущее.